# I have created single-spa application using create single-spa and its working fine in all browser except IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, single-spa, single-spa-angular

[IE11 error while running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bLeL.png)

Note: I have added core.js dependency, still getting error in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the following scripts to make single-spa work in IE 11?

```
<script>
  if (typeof fetch === 'undefined') {
    document.write('<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/whatwg-fetch@3.4.0/dist/fetch.umd.js"><\/script>')
  }
  if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith === 'undefined' || typeof Promise === 'undefined') {
    document.write('<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/polyfill@7.10.4/dist/polyfill.min.js"><\/script>')
  }
</script>
```

Besides, Webpack 5 which is used in single-spa doesn't support IE11 by default. To make it support IE11, you need to specify `target: ['web', 'es5']` in the **webpack.config.js**.

For more inforamtion, you can refer to [this similar thread](https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa/issues/740). If you still can't make it work in IE11, you can use [this working sample](https://github.com/joeldenning/single-spa-issue-740). It works well in IE11 and other browsers.

[image]